How to include binaries from 2 directories in make dist for rpmbuild
I have a Qt project and in that project i have the following directory structure:
/src (source of my main code that builds the main software product (including .pro file and .spec file))
/app (source code that builds an support app)
/bin (where the binary files from src and app are built to)

Currently I have a spec file in the main source directory that builds the rpm. This works fine.
In the app directory I have code that builds a support app for the application built in the src directory, this i build with a separate .pro file
and it builds and creates an executable fine.
At the moment after i build the app code I copy the app binary (from /bin) into the /src directory and just include
the binary in the main project by putting it in the DISTFILES section in the .pro file but this is not ideal.
The problem I have is I wish to build and include the executable from the /app directory in the rpm that is built from the /src directory,
so the rpm provides both executables, without having to build the /app directory separately and copying the executable across.
I want to be able to just do
qmake (in /src directory)
make dist
rpmbuild -ta app.tar.gz
and build executables in both directories for the rpm.
Currently if I don't put the /app executable in the /src directory "make dist" fails as of course the app file doesn't exist.
My question is how do i do this so the source code from the /app directory gets included into the tar.gz that make dist is creating from the /src directory?
(I would prefer not to move the .spec file from the src file if possible)
Thank you.

If you want an RPM that provides both components, then its build scriptlets should build both components from source.  It is highly undesirable for RPMs to package pre-built binaries.  That is occasionally done anyway, but mainly for reasons that do not seem to apply to you, such has having only a binary in the first place, not corresponding source.
